# Unable to change/set new linux time using php shell_exec function

Tags: javascript, php, linux, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to change the time of my Raspberry Pi using a php, JavaScript and shell_exec().

JavaScript code

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function settime()
    {
        var time = new Date();
        var date = time.getDate();
        var month = time.getMonth()+1;
        var year = time.getFullYear();
        var hours = time.getHours();
        var minutes = time.getMinutes();
        var seconds = time.getSeconds();

        document.getElementById("hh").value = hours;
        document.getElementById("minute").value = minutes;
        document.getElementById("ss").value = seconds;
        document.getElementById("dd").value = date;
        document.getElementById("mm").value = month;
        document.getElementById("yy").value = year;

        return true;
    }
```

Html Form I used

```
    &lt; form action="" method="post"&gt;

    &lt;input type="hidden"  id="hh" name="hh" /&gt;
    &lt;input type="hidden"  id="minute" name="minute" /&gt;
    &lt;input type="hidden"  id="ss" name="ss" /&gt;
    &lt;input type="hidden"  id="dd" name="dd" /&gt;
    &lt;input type="hidden"  id="mm" name="mm" /&gt;
    &lt;input type="hidden"  id="yy" name="yy" /&gt;

    &lt;input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="settime();" value="Set same as your device time" name="set_dt" /&gt;

    &lt;a class="btn btn-danger" href="" >Cancle changing time&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/form&gt;
```

And php scripts i used

```
if(isset($_POST['set_dt']))
{
    $time=$_POST['hh'].":".$_POST['minute'].":".$_POST['ss'];
    $dd="0";
    $mm="0";
    //To add 0 before date and month if less than 10 like => 09, 05, etc
    if($_POST['dd']<10)$dd.=$_POST['dd'];else $dd=$_POST['dd'];
    if($_POST['mm']<10)$mm.=$_POST['mm'];else $mm=$_POST['mm'];
    $date=$_POST['yy'].$mm.$dd;
    echo $date." ".$time;
    echo shell_exec('sudo date +%Y%m%d -s "$date"');
    echo shell_exec('sudo date +%T -s "$time"');
    shell_exec('hwclock -w');
}
```

all these codes are in same page "setting.php"

When i click `Set same as your device time` button, javascript function `settime()` fetch the correct time and assign to those hidden input fiels.

And time displayed by `echo $date." ".$time;`is in correct format.

code `echo shell_exec('sudo date +%Y%m%d -s "$date"');` Not working I mean it is not making any kind of change in date of Pi Linux

and when `echo shell_exec('sudo date +%T -s "$time"');` is executed it
display 00:00:00 always and pi time also become 00:00:00.

I don't know why it is not able to change date and time of machine.
I executed this task over hundreds of times but still date and time is not updated.
Kindly give some suggestions because it is the main part of my project.

I don't have any Real Time Clock device and Pi get restarted several times due to power cut and I don't have any battery for constant power supply.

Comment: Do you have NPT enabled on your Pi?

Comment: No, I not enabled NPT but actually I want to update my time with command `sudo date`. Sorry but I dont know how NPT works and how to use NPT and my raspberry pi dont have any RTC device and not connected to internet and Pi also get reboot around 2 to 5 times due to power cut and I dont have any constant power supply like battery for it.